# How to generate several html files with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to generate 2 html files after build and to include in first html only `.js` bundles(without head,body etc.), but in another `.css` bundle( without head,body etc.). How I understand in order to allow htmlWebpackPlugin to generate 2 htmls I need to specify in `webpack` config something like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './templates/index1.html',
            filename: '/templates/template1.html',

        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './templates/index2.html',
            filename: '/templates/template2.html',

        }),
```

But how can I separate bundles in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using multiple entry points.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'page1': './apps/page1/scripts/main.js',
    'page2': './apps/page2/src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "apps/[name]/build/bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      chunks: ['page1'],
      filename: 'apps/page1/build/index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      chunks: ['page2'],
      filename: 'apps/page2/build/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: with using  inject: false it desn't put any chunk to html. with js bundles it's workin, what about .css?(I generate it with text eextract plugin from js bundles)

Comment: Edited the answer with removing inject. and yes you can inject css file using textextractplugin